# Jenkins java.io.NotSerializableException when running slave on AWS ECS

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

A weird problem I came across: I run my slave as a docker image, sometimes as docker container on master node and other times on ECS(Fargate) using Amazon Elastic Container Service plugin.

I run this below piece of code

```
publishLambda(
       awsAccessKeyId:"${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}",
       awsSecretKey:"${env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}",
       awsRegion:"${lambda_config.region}",
       functionARN:lambda_name,
       functionAlias:"DEV"
      )
```

It works fine when I’m running the slave as docker container but when run on ECS, I get the following error **after the lambda gets published successfully**. I suspect its something with the *hudson.remoting* api when its trying to get a response across the network.

IMO hudson.remoting should be behaving the same irrespective of where the containers are running. How am i getting such discrepencies?

> java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.publish.LambdaPublishServiceResponse
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest._serialize(UserRequest.java:264)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:273) Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to
>   JNLP4-connect connection from
>   ec2-18-224-68-207.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/18.224.68.207:40038
>           at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
>           at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
>           at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
>           at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.publish.LambdaPublishBuildStep.perform(LambdaPublishBuildStep.java:58)
>           at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.publish.LambdaPublishBuildStep.perform(LambdaPublishBuildStep.java:46)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

---

> Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize
>   com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.publish.LambdaPublishServiceResponse@4ec0e00f
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:275)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:223)
>       at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
>       at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
>       at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)

---

> Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException
>       at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.publish.LambdaPublishBuildStep.perform(LambdaPublishBuildStep.java:66)
>       at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.publish.LambdaPublishBuildStep.perform(LambdaPublishBuildStep.java:46)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was Class **LambdaPublishServiceResponse** in **Amazon Elastic Container Service plugin** was not inheriting *java.io.Serializable*.

And since java remoting over network from slave running on ECS(fargate) had to be serialized to be retrieved by master, this change had to be done. Have raised a PR https://github.com/XT-i/aws-lambda-jenkins-plugin/pull/100